# Display GIF/Ajax loader in batch DOS window

Tags: batch-file

So,Ive researched a lot and I cannot find a way to display a animated gif in a batch file DOS window. Any ideas? I don't want to use the "ECHO,CLS" way and I want the batch file to look like this..

```
Loading...
[animated gif loading bar]
```

Comment: Is [this](https://www.tutorielsenfolie.com/en/tutorials-31-Display-a-progress-bar-in-a-batch-script.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Calling what you describe a gif is wrong. Gif doesn't mean "anything that is animated", but rather a very specific image format that is not related to console output in any way.